# How to replace a NULL when a COUNT(*) returns NULL in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query:

```
SELECT A.AHSHMT AS SHIPMENT, A.AHVNAM AS VENDOR_NAME, D.UNITS_SHIPPED, D.ADPON AS PO, B.NUMBER_OF_CASES_ON_TRANSIT, C.NUMBER_OF_CASES_RECEIVED FROM AHASNF00 A
      INNER JOIN (SELECT IDSHMT, COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_ON_TRANSIT FROM IDCASE00 WHERE IDSTAT = '01' GROUP BY IDSHMT) B 
        ON (A.AHSHMT = B.IDSHMT) 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT IDSHMT, (COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_RECEIVED FROM IDCASE00 WHERE IDSTAT = '10' GROUP BY IDSHMT) C 
        ON (A.AHSHMT = C.IDSHMT) 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ADSHMT, ADPON, SUM(ADUNSH) AS UNITS_SHIPPED FROM ADASNF00 GROUP BY ADSHMT, ADPON) D 
        ON (A.AHSHMT = D.ADSHMT) 
    WHERE A.AHSHMT = '540041134';
```

On the first JOIN statement I have a COUNT(*), on this count sometimes I will get NULL. I need to replace this with a "0-zero", I know think I know how to do it in SQL

```
ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)
```

But this doesn't work for DB2, how can I accomplish this? All your help is really appreciate it.

Comment: `count(*)` returns _null_? If there are no matching rows surely it returns 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a COALESCE around each of the nullable totals in your SELECT list:

```
SELECT A.AHSHMT AS SHIPMENT, 
A.AHVNAM AS VENDOR_NAME, 
COALESCE( D.UNITS_SHIPPED, 0 ) AS UNITS_SHIPPED,
D.ADPON AS PO, 
COALESCE( B.NUMBER_OF_CASES_ON_TRANSIT, 0 ) AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_ON_TRANSIT, 
COALESCE( C.NUMBER_OF_CASES_RECEIVED, 0 ) AS NUMBER_OF_CASES_RECEIVED
FROM ...
```

The inner joins you're using for expressions B and D mean that you will only receive rows from A that have one or more cases in transit (expression B) and have one or more POs in expression D. Is that the way you want your query to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0)`,

try using `COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)`

Answer (score 0):

use `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` for DB2